# Database Design: optional, but must be unique if provided a value

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a column in one of my tables. It's optional, so it can be left blank. However, if a value is provided for that column, it must be unique. Two questions:

1. How do I implement this in my database design (I'm using MySQL Workbench, by the way)
2. Is there a potential problem with my model?

Comment: Answer to (2). No, this is quite normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a `UNIQUE` index on the column.  See:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint
>   such that all values in the index must
>   be distinct. An error occurs if you
>   try to add a new row with a key value
>   that matches an existing row. For all
>   engines, a UNIQUE index permits
>   multiple NULL values for columns that
>   can contain NULL. If you specify a
>   prefix value for a column in a UNIQUE
>   index, the column values must be
>   unique within the prefix.

Answer (score 2):

It's can be null (and not blank) and unique. By default value can be null. There is no problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UNIQUE index on a table. In MySQL workbench that is the UQ checkbox when creating/editing the table.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, `ALTER` the table and `MODIFY` the field so `NULL`s are allowed.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY my_field VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Step 2, add a `UNIQUE` index on the field.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX U_my_field (my_field);
```

It's fine to use -- my only hesitation with putting a `UNIQUE` index on a nullable field it that it is slightly counter-intuitive at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Move the column to a new table, make it unique and non-nullable. You can now have a row in this new table only when you have a value for it.

2) Yes. Keys and dependencies on keys are the basis of data integrity in a relational database design. If an attribute is supposed to be unique then it should be implemented as a key. A nullable "key" is not a key at all and anyway is never necessary because it can always be moved to a new table and made non-nullable without loss of any information.